# Entity Framework. ExecuteStoreQuery Error converting data type varchar to real

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, sqlparameter

I'm trying to execute a story query with Entity Framework.

I've been trying this for ages. The data type I'm passing in starts off as double. I then found that real in SQL was a single, so I convert to single.

(radius is an int)

But I get this error.

Error converting data type varchar to real.

```
var query = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<SearchIndex>("select * FROM dbo.ItemsWidthinRadiusMilesSearchIndex('{0}','{1}','{2}')", Convert.ToSingle(geo.Latitude), Convert.ToSingle(geo.Longitude), radius).ToList();
```

Can anyone help?

Edit, problem still happening with this syntax:

```
SqlParameter lat = new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "p1", Value =      Convert.ToSingle(geo.Latitude) };
SqlParameter lng = new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "p2", Value = Convert.ToSingle(geo.Longitude) };
SqlParameter radiusParam = new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "p3", Value = radius, DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32 };
var paramsToPass = new object[] {lat,lng,radiusParam};
var query = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<SearchIndex>("select * FROM dbo.ItemsWidthinRadiusMilesSearchIndex('@p1','@p2','@p3')",paramsToPass).ToList();
```

Comment: Rewrite what you have into five lines of code.  Three to do the conversions, one to build the SQL string and one to execute it.  After that, I'll bet you'll be able to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Cool, I was doing that before, just switched to this method to try and post here. Will edit.

Comment: Should I be setting more of the SqlParamater options/params?

Comment: try to replace "," by "." `Convert.ToSingle(geo.Latitude).ToString().Replace(",",".")`

Comment: can you show us an example of the data your using as parameter ? You have a problem converting one of the parameters. Also show us the function in sql, what parameter types it expects ?

Comment: You need to break it down to one logical step per line:  single tempLatitude =  Convert.ToSingle(geo.Latitude);

Comment: Are you sure that the error is not caused by populating `SearchIndex`?

Comment: Remove the quotations from the parameter. e.g. @p1 instead of '@p1'

Comment: Ah, it was the quotes in the string! AkzenT, wanna put a question so you get the rep. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotations from the parameter. e.g. @p1 instead of '@p1' – aKzenT